# Best way to setup optional callbacks in a function

Tags: javascript, function, callback

What is the best practice for optional success and error callbacks in a function like this? Does this method make sense? It seems a little bloated to me.

**Function Declaration:**

```
var myFunc = function(myNumber, options){
    options = options || {};
    options.onSuccess = options.onSuccess || function(){};
    options.onError = options.onSuccess || function(){};

    var myNewNumber = myNumber * 2;

    if(newVar > 10){
        options.onSuccess(myNewNumber);
    }else{
        options.onError(myNewNumber);
    }
}
```

**Calling it with callbacks:**

```
myFunc(2,{
    onError: function(myNewNumber){
        // do stuff
    },
    onSuccess: function(myNewNumber){
        // do stuff
    }
})
```

**Calling it without callbacks:**

```
myFunc(2);
```

Comment: What you're doing here looks fine to me. What aspects are you looking for in terms of best practices? An alternative is to have a single callback with `error` as the first passed parameter, which is null when no error has occurred.

Comment: One problem I see is that you are not checking if the onSuccess and onError (you have a typo there) are functions or not. Might want to add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it by checking the existence of the functions before calling them:

```
var myFunc = function(myNumber, options){
    options = options || {};

    var myNewNumber = myNumber * 2;

    if(newVar > 10){
        if (options.onSuccess) { options.onSuccess(myNewNumber); }
    }else{
        if (options.onError) { options.onError(myNewNumber); }
    }
}
```

It depends how many times you are likely to call these callbacks. If it is all over the place then your way might be better, or at least cleaner code.

Comment: For my case I think this answer is the most suitable :)

Answer (score 4):

A few things to note;

1. `options.onSuccess = options.onSuccess || function(){};` is checking for the existance of the member, rather than checking its a function.

   You might want `options.onSuccess = (typeof options.onSuccess == "function") ? options.onSuccess : function () { };`
2. The same goes for `onError`
3. As as slight optimisation, you could point the empty function to the same function; rather than recreating it potentially twice. If you're using jQuery, jQuery defines [`jQuery.noop()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noop):

   ```
   options.onSuccess = options.onSuccess || jQuery.noop;
   options.onError = options.onSuccess || jQuery.noop;
   ```
4. In the situation where the callbacks are asynchronous, you would be leaving yourself open to the `options.onSuccess` and `options.onError` being changed after your check, but before the callback is fired;

   ```
   var myFunc = function(myNumber, options){
       options = options || {};
       options.onSuccess = options.onSuccess || function(){};
       options.onError = options.onSuccess || function(){};

       var myNewNumber = myNumber * 2;

       setTimeout(function () {
           if(newVar > 10){
               options.onSuccess(myNewNumber);
           }else{
               options.onError(myNewNumber);
           }
       }, 2000);
   }

   var obj = {
       success: function () { alert('foo'); },
       error: function () { alert('foo'); },
   };

   myFunc(10, obj);
   delete obj.success;
   delete obj.error;
   ```

   When the callback gets executed, `success` and `error` will be undefined.

Comment: Thank a lot! I guess the kind of detail you want to go into depends on whether this is a public API or just used internally. In my case it is just internally so I know that functions will be function etc.